# How to display '-' character in a cell when actual value is 0 (Zero) in ExcelJS

Tags: javascript, exceljs

This is easily done on Excel with custom formatting; but I don't find out how to do it programmatically in Javascript (ExcelJS). I don't want to replace the value, just how it is displayed.

[image: view excel sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to accomplish this, it may help others. So here is it:

```js
worksheet.getCell('A1').numFmt = '_(#,##0_);_( (#,##0);_( \\-\\ ??_);_(@_)';
```

Comment: If there is a better way please advice.